# Почему не работает trimpath?

Tags: golang, stacktrace

Есть файлы:

```golang
//-----BEGIN FILE /tmp/example.com/internal/internal.go-----
package internal

import "golang.org/x/xerrors"

func Do() error {
    return xerrors.New("internal")
}

//-----END FILE /tmp/example.com/internal/internal.go-----
```

```golang
//-----BEGIN FILE /tmp/example.com/main.go-----
func main() {
    var err = do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%+v", err)
    }
}

func do() error {
    var err = internal.Do()
    if err != nil {
        return xerrors.Errorf("main: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

//-----END FILE /tmp/example.com/main.go-----
```

Запускаю:

```sh
$ go run -gcflags "-trimpath=/tmp" main.go
```

Вижу:

```
2019/04/09 18:44:52 main:
    main.do
        example.com/main.go:21
  - internal:
    example.com/internal.Do
        /tmp/example.com/internal/internal.go:6
exit status 1
```

Почему убрался префикс только у `package main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация флага `-gcflags`:

```
    -gcflags '[pattern=]arg list'
        arguments to pass on each go tool compile invocation.
```

В данном случае, `pattern` должен быть `all`:

```sh
$ go run -gcflags "all=-trimpath=/tmp" main.go
```

```
2019/04/09 18:50:47 main:
    main.do
        example.com/main.go:22
  - internal:
    example.com/internal.Do
        example.com/internal/internal.go:7
exit status 1
```